# Exact results in having SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

So i'm trying to get the Exact results with having function and i've tried many ways but with no success.

The story is that i've this SQL query:

```
SELECT 
    SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS customers.*, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(fieldsContent.Content SEPARATOR '%||%') AS Content, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(fieldsContent.FieldID SEPARATOR '%||%') AS FieldID, 
    customers.Created, 
    customers.ID
FROM (`customers`)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN `fieldsContent` ON `fieldsContent`.`TypeID` = `customers`.`ID`
    HAVING Content LIKE "%2%" AND LIKE "%new%"
    GROUP BY `fieldsContent`.`TypeID`
    ORDER BY `customers`.`Created` DESC
```

RESULT:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [ID] => 4857
    [Created] => 1403714637
    [Content] => newman%||%noman%||%newemail@gmail.com%||%92292%||%old%||%7
    [FieldID] => C359FE4B-7A5B-689F-8A26-D030CFC65475%||%E34399EB-0509-2F00-EAD1-38753FCAEA5C%||%3172E7F4-B445-2F7A-74C8-F9C9E85A4C22%||%26D87695-D9F4-9E2F-2BA7-753FBF3E0BBA%||%E443B0BD-5283-CD02-F569-3B05B615B5BC%||%979C2844-870F-961F-FA28-12AC615346E5
)
stdClass Object
(
    [ID] => 175997
    [Created] => 1403714632
    [Content] => john%||%doe%||%google@gmail.com%||%0847%||%new%||%2
    [FieldID] => C359FE4B-7A5B-689F-8A26-D030CFC65475%||%E34399EB-0509-2F00-EAD1-38753FCAEA5C%||%3172E7F4-B445-2F7A-74C8-F9C9E85A4C22%||%26D87695-D9F4-9E2F-2BA7-753FBF3E0BBA%||%E443B0BD-5283-CD02-F569-3B05B615B5BC%||%979C2844-870F-961F-FA28-12AC615346E5
)
```

The problem is i only want the second result, only where i have the word "new" and "2",
not where is the word "new" appears like newman and the number 2 appears like "92292".

So i need only the second result, not the first.

The main thing is, that i exactly know after which separator the word "new" will be and "2" will be, and i've no idea how to apply it, because "new" always will be after the 4th separator and "2" will be after the 5th separator.

Any crazy ideas how to solve this problem?
Thanks!

Comment: Why use having instead of where? Also, is new always wrapped with percentile signs in the actual text?

Comment: @SpectralGhost because where is not an option. i need the all length of the `Content` column, and if i will do `where` it will destroy my group by for all of the data i need to retrieve

Comment: What SQL flavor is this?  MySQL?

Comment: Using % as part of a separator is a really bad idea for SQL

Comment: Have you tried replacing `HAVING Content LIKE "%2%" AND LIKE "%new%"` with `HAVING Content IN ("2","new")` if you want exact matches?

Comment: @MartinK. why not using "%" as a separator?

Comment: Because it is the wildcard in SQL and even if you only use it in your application above it is quite confusing as you can see in the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
HAVING Content LIKE "%2%" AND LIKE "%new%"
```

To this:

```
HAVING Content LIKE "%\%2" ESCAPE "\" AND LIKE "%\%new\%%" ESCAPE "\"
```

This presumes you are looking for the 2 at the end of the string for FieldID "979C2844-870F-961F-FA28-12AC615346E5". If you need it to be any more flexible, you might want to change this up to a where clause (which won't ruin the grouping) and select FieldID/Content pairs specifically in sub queries.

Also, I suggest using a different separator, so you don't need to do escapes with like.

Comment: You right, i've changed the separators. Nice way of thinking, simple and good. works good, thanks!